# OnItemClickListener doesnt get called when using ViewPager in a Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` in a `ListView`. Everything works fine ( vertical scroll in list view / horizontal scroll in `ViewPager`). But I am having problems catching on click event on the listview items (the viewpager  fills the listview item).

**So far I tried**

- set the list view to clickable
- extended `Viewpager` and added a gesture detector which detects horizontal scroll and sets 
  `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)` if the gesture is not horizontal scroll
- set `setOnItemClickListener` for my list view

**problem**: `setOnItemClickListener`  doesn't get called

I was also trying to add the onclick listner dirrectly to the viewPager but the listner was not called aswell

Basicly I am looking for a sollution which I can detect a click on the listview item or the page viewer and launch a intent.

P.S Any links on how android handles touch events on views will be also appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close, but instead of setting an `onClickListener` on the `ViewPager` itself, you must set an `onClickListener` to the view in the `ViewPager`'s [`PagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html) (which you must extend).

In your `ListView`'s `getView()`, where you instantiate the `ViewPager`, set an adapter to your PagerAdapter (here called "ExtendedPagerAdapter):

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) container.findViewById(R.id.pager);
ExtendedPagerAdapter adapter = new ExtendedPagerAdapter(context, list);
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then, in your ExtendedPagerAdapter class, you override (among other things) `instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)`.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
        context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View theView = list.get(position).getView(inflater);

    theView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //perform action
        }
    });

    container.addView(theView, 0);
    return theView;
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue , But I don't want to set the listener to ViewPager , I need to set it to items by onItemClickListener , Any suggestion ?