# ListView doesn't accept onClickListener when list item contains ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have a list view and inside it's items I have a view pager as you can see in the below code.
While the viewPager is inside the item view List doesn't accept onItemClickListener and when I click Items nothing happens.

One solution that I found was adding onClickListener to ViewPager pages , But I think this is not a good solution because If you list contains 100 Items and each item have a view pager that contains 5 page so I should define 500 Listener Instead of one Listener.

I tried all solutions that I searched for example changing the focusable or clickable attribute of root view.

Please share your suggestions with me.

This is the list item layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/propertylist_item_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/purple"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

    <!-- background slider -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/property_images_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- favorite icon -->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/favorite_button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/favorite_button_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite" />
        ...

    <!-- Some other tags -->
```

This is the list adapter code :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.property_listing_item, parent, false);
    }

    RPropertyStorage property = getItem(position);

    if (property != null)
    {
        PropertyListingImagesAdapter adapter = new PropertyListingImagesAdapter(property.getImages());
        ViewPager imagesPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.property_images_view_pager);
        imagesPager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        imagesPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    return view;
}
```

OnItemClickListener of ListView :

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3)
    {
        RToast.getInstance().showMessage("Clicked");

        RLog.info("Clicked");
    }

});
```

Comment: have you added `android:focusable = false` to your viewpager?

Comment: @mmlooloo No I added it to RelativeLayout , I should add it to ViewPager ?

Comment: yes because it takes the focus!

Comment: @mmlooloo Let me check it.

Comment: @mmlooloo Nothing changed , Still same issue , And When I comment the ViewPager in layout click listener works fine.

Comment: also try to remove `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` then add `android:focusable = false`

Comment: i have same problem!

Comment: Hi, There i was facing the same issue and what worked for me was to implement on click listener in the adapter on parent view. please refer the url for code.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515158/onitemclicklistener-doesnt-get-called-when-using-viewpager-in-a-listview

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager has very "strong" code that handle touch events. For me it is only one way to catch viewpager clicks through it's own clicklisteners.

Don't care about

> If you list contains 100 Items and each item have a view pager that contains 5 page so I should define 500 Listener Instead of one Listener.

because listview creates only as many view as can display on the screen at the same time + 2; You can check it by such code in your adapter

```
int count=0;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.property_listing_item, parent, false);
        Log.v("","creating "+count);
        count++;

    }

    //your code
}
```

Listener is only links. It is no matter how many links you have on some method. Just check if it is not null.